# Displaying Jsoup elements

Tags: java, javascript, android, jquery, jsoup

//     I have this AsynchTask gets the body of a website blog. However, it doesn't show anything when method is initiated.

```
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements elements = document.select("div.pst-content safety clearfix entry-content p");
           for(Element elements123 : elements){
           title+=elements123.text();
           System.out.println(elements123.text());

           }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Set title into TextView
        TextView txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titletxt);
        txttitle.setText(title);
       // System.out.println(title);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: Not that it solves anything but you shouldn't use `title+=elements123.text()` in loop. Instead you should `append` new elements to `StringBuilder`. Anyway are you sure that your code handling URL is correct? Did you test this `select` query in simple Java application (lets say in main method)?

Comment: i tried selecting "a" and it works. maybe its just the query?

Comment: It is possible. If your code works for one query and doesn't for other then either there is problem with this other query, or you are parsing wrong data. Consider printing `document` to see if it really contains `div.pst-content` and other elements you need (it may be possible that this content is generated dynamically by JavaScript, in this case you will need web-driver like selenium instead of simple parser like Jsoup).

Answer (score 0):

Definetly the CSS Selector is wrong.

If it is working with a selector `a` and is not working with ur current one, the problem is the CSS Selector `div.pst-content safety clearfix entry-content p`

If u can tell what u are trying to extract from the HTML or the webpage might be helpuful to solve ur problem. Take fun with JSoup –